# Add a delimiter at the end of each line in csv.writer

Tags: python, csv

I use the function below, but I get problem when reading it with as a dict for example. But if I add a delimiter as a last character in the header it works.

The code produce csv as:

```
Username;Name;Lastname
```

I use this function to create the csv's:

```
def create_csv_with_data(data, dst):
    '''
    Create a CSV from a list with lists.
    '''
    with open(dst, 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        for i in data:
            writer.writerow(i)
    print(str(dst) + ' file created.')
```

Expected output:

```
Username;Name;Lastname;
```

Comment: The output should be the filename surely?

Comment: Add an empty string to the end of each row e.g. `i + ['']` if `i` is a `list` or `i + ('',)` if `i` is a `tuple`.

Comment: The question is why do you want a delimiter at the end of the line? Do really want an empty column with an empty header?

Comment: "*reading it with as a dict"* What is this supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`lineterminator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) option:

```
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator=';\n')
```